# How to show a nested list in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three arrays `persons`, `skills` and `personSkills`. Now I want to show all skills for each person in a unordered vertical list, like this

- Person1
  - Skill1
  - Skill2
- Person2
  - Skill3
  - Skill4

Here's my code-

```
let persons = ["Person1", "Person2"];
let skills = ["Skill1", "Skill2", "Skill3", "Skill4"];

export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      personSkills: [
        { Person1: ["Skill1", "Skill2"] },
        { Person2: ["Skill3", "Skill4"] }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {persons.map((eachP) => (
          <ul>
            {eachP}

            {this.state.personSkills.map((eachPS) => {
              eachPS[eachP] && eachPS[eachP].map((eachS) => <li>{eachS}</li>);
            })}
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But it just shows

- Person1
- Person2

Here's a link to my sandbox - [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-list-render-problem-zh1gc?file=/src/App.js:51-702)

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify the way you store the skills as follows:

```
this.state = {
      personSkills: {
        Person1: ["Skill1", "Skill2"],
        Person2: ["Skill3", "Skill4"]
      }
};
```

Now while rendering:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {persons.map((eachP) => (
          <ul>
            {eachP}
            {this.state.personSkills[eachP] && this.state.personSkills[eachP].map((skill) => {
              return <li>{skill}</li>;
            })}
          </ul>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `map` function expects a return statement.
So you need to modify your code to something like

```
{this.state.personSkills.map((eachPS) => {
  return eachPS[eachP] && eachPS[eachP].map((eachS) => <li>{eachS}</li>);
})}
```